# Open the GUI application remotely from Ubuntu 16.04 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, ssh, 18.04, gui

I have Ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop and I use `ssh -X` to access Ubuntu 16.04 in a workstation. I can open some graphical application from Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop like xmgrace but I can not open others like xcrysden.

How to open all the graphics applications in my laptop without downgrading to Ubuntu 16.04? And does the downgrading solve the problem?

The error message that I get when trying to open xcrysden :

> X Error of failed request: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)

Comment: I downgrade to ubuntu 16.04 and still can not open xcrysden via ssh

Comment: some GUI windows will not open due to missing rights: The password request does not appear. Stale situation. Other windows have severe difficulty and can not be displayed. Lately a printer config GUI appeared only to show some unrelated warning every second. Beside time out there are many issues with GUI windows forwarded via X. This will not happen with Wayland any more ....

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in case someone facing the same problem, I figured out that the problem was with the internet connection. It was so slow that the GUI applications cannot open. When I used faster internet connection I was able to open GUI applications.